# Fill in table after form submit in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need the table to populate after I submit a form to an api in ASP.NET c#, the api request send the data back and then the table needs to fill.

At the moment I tried to check if the form value is null or not, and after the submit it does show the table, but not the data inside the table.

How do you make it so that after the form submit, the data from the api shows?

```js
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
              info: [],
              IngredientCategory: '',
              IngredientCategory1: '',

            },
            methods: {
                getFormValues() {
                    console.log("test " + this.IngredientCategory);
                    axios
                        .get("https://localhost:44331/Api/ShowRecipes/"+ this.ingredientCategory + "/" + this.ingredientCategory1 )
                        .then(response => this.info.concat(response.data))
                },
            }
        });
```

html

```
            <table v-if="info !== null">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>IngredientCategory</th>
                        <th>IngredientName</th>
                        <th>Calories</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="inf in info" :key="inf.Id">
                        <td>{{inf.Id}}</td>
                        <td>{{inf.IngredientCategory}}</td>
                        <td>{{inf.IngredientName}}</td>
                        <td>{{inf.Calories}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <form @@submit.prevent="getFormValues()">
            <input type="text"  v-model="IngredientCategory">
            <input type="text" ref="IngredientCategory1" v-model="IngredientCategory1">
            <button>Get values</button>
        </form>
```

api data

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "IngredientName": "something",
        "IngredientCategory": "test",
        "Calories": 100
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "IngredientName": "something",
        "IngredientCategory": "test",
        "Calories": 100
    },
]
```

...

Answer (score 0):

If your response is coming as an array of single object

you can push it directly to info

```
axios.get("https://localhost:44331/Api/ShowRecipes/"+ this.ingredientCategory + "/" + this.ingredientCategory1 )
.then(response => this.info.push(response.data[0]))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The api gives multiple objects with it

Comment: Then you can use `this.info.concat(response.data)`

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I've tried this, had to change `info` in data to `''` or else it would give me a type error of null. When I press submit, the table stays empty and there are no more errors in the console.

Comment: info will be `[]` not `' '`

Comment: I tried [] but it gives me nothing as well (also no errors) weirdly

Comment: Can you change the `data() {}` to `data: {}`. Also no return needed

Comment: Hmm still no results. I've updated the post with the current edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215327/discussion-between-n212-and-wulfnb).